Cannot launch terminal after upgrading to noble
I just upgraded to Noble 24.04.1 a week ago but cannot lauch a terminal, ergo cannot run apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop. How can I workaround this?
I tried ctl-ALT-T and got nothing.
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If terminal does not work, you will have to use a virtual terminal, as described in the answer. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes and no. The answer you quoted is very helpful and I wish I knew that ctl-Alt-F3 invokes a virtual terminal, but the comment that the writer thought, like I did, that 6 months after the release of Noble and with the point release one would expect that everything was clean. Bad assumption!

The upgrade path is only one week old.

I rebooted twice more and the terminal works - go figure!
